# NSExpression Dividing Lower Number By Higher Number

Tags: swift, nsexpression

I'm trying to divide in this case 5/10 using NSExpression but it returns 0 instead of 0.5.

```
let expn = NSExpression(format:"5/10")

let answer = expn.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? NSNumber
```

And Ideas?

Comment: NSExpression is very restricted and that is one of its limitations.

Comment: NSExpression is a Foundation class. The question and its answers are independent of whether you use it from Objective-C or Swift.